# Request PUT with little JSON : 1000MB transferred

Tags: angular, symfony, httprequest

I'm trying to make a put request from my Angular client to my symfony server.

Here is my Symfony function :

```
    /**
     * @Rest\Put(path = "/my_path", name="my_path")
     * @Rest\View(StatusCode=204)
     * @param Request $request
     * @return string
     */
    public function changeCheckCalendarAction(Request $request) {
        var_dump($request); 
        return "test";
    }
```

My REST configuration may be useful :

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener:
        array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
          - { priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    view:
        view_response_listener: force
```

And here is my request in Angular :

```
myPutRequest(my_string: string) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('my_string', my_string);
    return this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:8000/my_path', formData);
}
```

When this function is call in my client side, my browser kill my page after 20sec  because I have more than 1000MB transfered. I have no idea where this may come from.

I have GET and POST requests and both work well.

Comment: what do you get when you log my_string to the console?

Comment: The `var_dump()` in my controller symfony doesn't works. In Angular I have just a random string like 'toto'. I can see this string in my HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. The `var_dump($request)` is the cause of the transfert.